# Best way of making an Ajax call from Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to just load a page using AJAX like this, I am very new to Jquery and ajax,please let me know what mistake I am doing here, always i get the error page.

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ajax-panel">

</div>
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.cnn.com',
   success:function(data){
   alert(data);
  },
  error:function(){
    // failed request; give feedback to user
    $('#ajax-panel').html('</p> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
  }
});
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any error? What's `data` value ?

Comment: You cannot load from just any site, unless they allow you to do so via CORS.

Comment: You are making a cross-domain request which is not allowed unless using the JSONP datatype or CORS

Answer (score 3):

You can't make *AJAX requests to a page on another domain.  You'll want to read about [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and look into your options.  The easest way is to poll a back end resource on your server that aggregates the data for you

Comment: My mistake, I meant AJAX but was thinking JSONP.

Comment: I replaced the URL with an internal URL that gives a JSON response, the alert is not working at all, instead it goes to the error function.It will be nice if you can give me any working example using a URL.

Comment: Hello any live examples using Ajax ?